# Serial Communication with iOS External Accessory (without authentication coprocessor)

Tags: external, serial-communication, mfi, accessory

It's my first question on stackoverflow. We're developing iOS external accessory under MFi program. (serial communication using lightning connector) However, we have some problems.

Background

1. We already completed device design and non-working mock ups
2. As a start-up, MFi certification was delayed (Finally we got it)
3. So, we've designed / developed PCB board without apple authentication coprocessor before MFi certification. (of course, we'll redesign with certified IC)
4. We have target demo day to potential clients. We don't have enough time to redesign with certified IC.

In this situation, we look forward to alternative ways

1. Without certified IC / authentication process, we completed iOS external accessory, anyway.
2. Jailbreak iphone 4/4S for serial communication with working mock-up (I found we can't jailbreak iphone5, so convert lightning connector to 30pin)

I need some advices that alternative way above is proper and possible way or not. I need your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a quite a few differences between the 30-pin and lightning connector in how iOS communicates with external accessories. If you've already developed your firmware, switching to 30-pin may introduce problems. There is a jailbreak for iPhone 5 that was released a few weeks ago, but I'm not aware of any tools for it that allow you to fake to iOS's External Accessory framework that your accessory contains the authentication processor.

The ideal solution would be to redesign your PCB to include the authentication processor. You will have to do this anyway, and it may not take nearly as long as trying to hack iOS on a jailbroken phone.